# is it necessary to define a variable before using Concatenation assignment operator in php?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I've tried and came to know that if i use

```
$a .="test";
$a .=" test2";
```

and echo out $a

```
echo $a
```

it returns

```
test test2
```

also for arrays

```
<?php 
$testarray['Title'] = "test";
$testarray['text'] = "text";
 print_r($testarray); 

 ?>
```

it gives the proper result without declaring $testarray=[];

```
Array ( [Title] => test [text] => text )
```

It does not even shows the warning or notice.. so i just want to know is it good practice to declare the variable before or both are ok.. also if it is related to any particular php version.. i am using php 7.1 will it show error in earlier version?

Comment: Did you *tell* it to show warnings or notices?

Comment: yes.. it shows Notice in String concatenation operator but nothing in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, not necessary but it is good practice to declare/initialize your variables first.

Actually, if you follow any coding standards you would clearly **avoid** using the concatenation assignment operator; *you get the PHP notice for a reason* for doing so.

The second case is not necessarily bad. If an array variable is used in a closure and there is no ambiguity it's arguably fine. But if we talking about a large file, a class property, or another critical piece, you arguably still doing it wrong when you use (associative) arrays that way.

The general advice here is, follow the coding standards that the framework at hand puts forth. Most bigger frameworks have a coding guide (here is a nice [overview](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149303/naming-classes-methods-functions-and-variables)), otherwise stick to [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) and [PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md) or some custom coding standard (e.g. [this](https://gist.github.com/ryansechrest/8138375)); the important thing is: **be consistent**.